# Converting from JQuery to plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are trying to convert several JQuery commands to plain JavaScript.
Can the following be converted?

Please note that the class **.options** is just a div container that contains all the input elements of interest.

```
var inputs = $(".options :input:not(:radio):not(:checkbox):not(.nofilter):not(.tt-hint)").filter(function () { return $(this).val(); }).length;
```

Comment: @Snow. Well it shouldn't be impossible as JQuery is based on JS.

Comment: It is possible... But what have you tried so far? SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette Sure. We know how to get all the inputs using querySelectorAll("input"), but there seems to be no way to exclude (i.e. filter) some of the inputs.

Comment: If you are asking how, the initial unknown is if `:input` needs to include `<select>` and `<textarea>` as the jQuery pseudo selector does

Comment: The filter method already is plain JS. The possible issue I see is about `return $(this).val()` where is has to be a boolean needed by the filter method. So... I am just unsure it works correctly as posted...

Comment: @user2981411 Use `Array.from( queryCollection).`

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const plainInputs = [...document.querySelectorAll(".options input, select, textarea, password")]
  .filter(ele => ele.value &&
    !["radio", "checkbox"].includes(ele.type) &&
    !ele.classList.contains("nofilter") &&
    !ele.classList.contains("tt-hint")
  ).length;

console.log(plainInputs)

const jQueryInputs = $(".options :input:not(:radio):not(:checkbox):not(.nofilter):not(.tt-hint)").filter(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).length;

console.log(jQueryInputs)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options">
  <input type="radio" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
  <textarea class="nofilter">3</textarea>
  <textarea class="tt-hint">4</textarea><br/>
  <input value="5"/><input value="6"/><input value="7"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Your code looks solid but unfortunately does not work. It seems to produce null for the ele and hence throws exception for classList and contains methods. But thanks anyeway.

Comment: Please see update. I did not read your selector correctly because I did not have any HTML to look at

Comment: Fantastic. Now I see why you have 133k reputation. Well done.